# How to exclude TODO state change messages from export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Org-Mode can automatically track TODO state changes as described [in the docs](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html). It also allows the option `todo: nil` option, [as mentioned here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html), so that TODO keywords will not appear in an export.

It seems rather intuitive to me that if I set `todo: nil` then I don't want messages like `• State “NEXT” from "" [2015-04-23 Thu 18:44]` to appear when I export. But they do appear, at least for me they do, in Org-Mode version 8.2.10.

If there is another option to do what I want, I'm not seeing it. Does anyone have a good fix for this?

Comment: Looks like you can put todo-items into drawers: `org-log-into-drawer` and control which drawers you export. See export-option `:with-drawers` `org-export-with-drawers` (http://orgmode.org/org.html). Note, that I did not try that. Therefore, it is only a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Maybe, the right way to hide drawers is `(require 'org-exp)` and customization of `org-export-with-drawers` or just evaluating `(setq org-export-with-drawers nil)`.

Comment: I gave this a quick test and drawers are apparently hidden by default. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

Setting the variable `org-log-into-drawer` will put new logs inside a drawer, one called `:LOGBOOK:` by default. Logs inside drawers are not exported by default.

This does not solve the problem of existing logs which are not already in drawers, but it certainly helps.